# bootstrap panel is stretching to top and hiding elements there in MD/Small devices

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, panel, responsive

I have a very simple bootstrap panel, but when I am using it within external div, it is stretching to top and hiding existing controls.

You will see that below fiddle when viewing in full screen it is showing correctly but as soon as I am resizing browser or viewing on Mobile mode, panel start moving upwards and hiding existing content.

```html
<div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top: 8px!important;">
    <div class="">
        <button type="button"
                class="close remove-cart-item update-cart-item"
                data-dismiss="alert"
                style="padding-right: 10px">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-10 nopadding">
        More Description : 
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control textArea"
                   maxlength="10"
                   size="10"
                   placeholder="Enter data Plate">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-10 nopadding">
            <select class="form-control textArea licenseStateDD" placeholder="Enter License State">
                <option value="TX">TEXAS</option>
                <option value="UT">UTAH</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Full version of the code can be found [on this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsqeb3wk/2/).

Answer (score 0):

`<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>`

Don't add the div part instead use the above part. It will hopefully help. After you've tried it let me know if it worked. You should end the div in which input tag is there n after that open panel div.

Comment: This is still not solving my problem, when I am resizing the browser, that div is going and mixing with controls above it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Panel div height takes the complete area and not resizing responsively, may be you could try to reset the panel body height like so:

```
 .panel-body {
  height: 75%;
}
.panel {
  height: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

On mobile screen size detection apply this height using the jquery resize
http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<style type="text/css"> 
.panel-heading h3 {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
line-height: normal;
width: 75%;
padding-top: 8px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<label class="transponderSelection nopadding">




<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
<img class="img-responsive" id="image_2" alt="Movie" title="Movie">
</div>
    <span id="validateTransponder_0" style="display:none">false</span>

    <p id="currentTransponderLongDescr_0" style="white-space: normal;">
        Releasing soon.
    </p>
    <p id="" hidden="">
        2
    </p>

<div class="selectionArea">
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2 numbers-row" style="padding-bottom:15px!important">
        <input type="text"  style="width: 30px; margin-left: 5px;" >
    </div>

    </div>

    <br>
<div class="purchase-details col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" >


<div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-top: 8px!important;">
    <div><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button></div>

    <div class="panel-body" >
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-10">
            <label class="col-md-12" style="padding-right:0px">License :</label>
            <div class="control-div col-md-12 col-xs-12 licensePlate" style="padding-bottom:7px">
                <input type="text"  class="form-control textArea licensePlate" maxlength="10" size="10" placeholder="Enter License Plate">
                </div>
            </div>



        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-10">
            <label class="col-md-12" style="padding-right:0px">Plate State:                              </label>
            <div class="control-div col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-    bottom:7px">
                <select class="form-control textArea licenseStateDD"     placeholder="Enter License State">
<option value="TX">TEXAS</option>
<option value="UT">UTAH</option>

       </select>

            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
</div>

       </div>





       </body>
       </html>
```

I just added break in between.